# Get image width and height before loading it completely in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I am loading an image in my UITableViewCell using

> [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl]

For setting custom height for my tableview cell , i need the actual size of the image that am loading.

Can we get the width and height of an image before loading it completely ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure -- but I would assume, based on how browsers load images, that different kinds of images have varying meta-data describing their dimensions.  If you've ever loaded a large JPG, you'll see that in your browser, it has the ability to resize and load parts of the image as it loads.  However, other image types will completely load before resized in the browser.  Your best bet, without a whole lot of data manipulation to find dimensions, would be to store the image sizes in a seperate medium.  That way you could get that information before pulling down the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSData` is an "opaque" data, so you cannot do much with it before converting it to something more "useful" (e.g., creating an `UIImage` by means of it `-initWithData:` method). At that moment you could enquiry the image size, but it would be late for you.

The only approach I see, if you really need knowing the image size before the image is fully downloaded, is implementing a minimal server-side API so that you can ask for the image size before trying to download it.

Anyway, why do you need to know the image size before it is actually downloaded? Could you not set the row height at the moment when it has been downloaded (i.e., from your request delegate method)?

Answer (score 7):

Try the Image I/O interface as done below. This will allow you to get the image size without having to load the entire file:

```
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>

NSMutableString *imageURL = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myimageurl.com/image.png"];

CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL], NULL);
NSDictionary* imageHeader = (__bridge NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
NSLog(@"Image header %@",imageHeader);
NSLog(@"PixelHeight %@",[imageHeader objectForKey:@"PixelHeight"]);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! This should be the accepted answer. Don't forget the memory management for the source and the header dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

you can do it like this:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
NSLog(@"image height: %f",image.size.height);
NSLog(@"image width: %f",image.size.width);
```

Comment: The question states "before loading it completely"..

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this Question [How do I extract the width and height of a PNG from looking at the header in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16724849/1059705) which shares how is it possible to parse image Meta-data.

I have a created OpenSource project [***`Ottran`***](https://github.com/07cs07/Ottran) that extracts the image size  and type of a remote image by downloading as little as possible, which supports `PNG`, `JPEG` , `BMP` and `GIF` formats.

Answer (score 2):

`dataWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous it will block your UI until its download complete, so please use header content to get resolution, Below is **Swift 3.0** code

```
 if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url! as CFURL, nil) {
     if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
          let pixelWidth = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
          let pixelHeight = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
          print("the image width is: \(pixelWidth)")
          print("the image height is: \(pixelHeight)")
       }
   }
```