# How do I extract the width and height of a PNG from looking at the header in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, header, binary, nsdata

I have a need to find the dimensions of images online without downloading them. To accomplish this I do this:

```
+ (CGSize) getImageDimensions:(NSString *)url {

   // Send a synchronous request
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    NSString *rangeString = [url hasSuffix: @"png"] ? @"bytes=0-100" : @"bytes=0-1300";
    [urlRequest setValue:rangeString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                          returningResponse:&response
                                                      error:&error];
    if (error == nil)
        return [UIImage imageWithData: data].size;
    else
        return CGSizeMake(0, 0);

}
```

This (downloading the first 100 bytes) surprisingly works and I get the correct dimensions for PNGs this way.

However I do not think this is a very elegant approach. First, I chose to download the first 100 bytes by just guess and checking, making it as small as possible whilst still having it work okay.

Apparently in a PNG file there's this thing called a IHDR in the header and I have to find it and directly after it are the width and height. This gives me the impression that I should loop over the data and find this IHDR and get the dimensions. The problem is, when I NSLog the data I get something like this:

```
... 49484452 000003b7 000001a7 08060000 006c2da0 b100000a 41694343 50494343 2050726f 66696c65 ...
```

I have no idea how to handle looping over my NSData object and detecting the IHDR token and then converting the things that come after it to numbers. I also have no idea if requesting just 100 bytes for a PNG is requesting too much just to get the dimensions, or if it's requesting not enough

Comment: `NSString *convertedData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:someData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Rationale

According to the [PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/png-1.2.pdf):

> The ﬁrst **eight** bytes of a PNG ﬁle always contain the following
>   (decimal) values: 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10

So you have to read those to make sure you really have a PNG file.

Then,

> The IHDR chunk must appear FIRST. It contains:
>
> Width: 4 bytes
>
> Height: 4 bytes
>
> etc...

So according to the structure of chunks, you first have to read the **four** bytes representing the length of the chunk's data field, then the **four** bytes representing the chunk's name, then the two 32-bit integers representing width and height, **eight** bytes in total.

So, the exact minimal number of bytes you must read in order to determine width and height is 8 + 4 + 4 + 8 = **24 bytes**.

### Objective-C code

Once you have your NSData object, you simply have to access the bytes that it contains:

```
unsigned char buffer[24];
[data getBytes:buffer length:24];
```

Optionally, but I recommend it strongly, check that you indeed have a PNG file:

```
unsigned char png_header[] = {137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10};
if (memcmp(buffer, png_header, 8)) {
     // this is not a PNG !
}
```

Make sure you have an IHDR:

```
unsigned char ihdr_name[] = "IHDR";
if (memcmp(buffer+8+4, ihdr_name, 4)) {
    // not an IHDR chunk, invalid PNG file
}
```

Width and height can be accessed as **big-endian** encoded unsigned ints at offset 24 minus 8 and minus 4 bytes respectively:

```
unsigned int width = OSReadBigInt32(buffer + 24 - 8);
unsigned int height = OSReadBigInt32(buffer + 24 - 4);
```

**Edit**: Fixed buffer reading code: PNG actually stores integers in big-endian.

Comment: Good answer.  You could make a `struct` type for `buffer` to avoid needing offset and size constants.

Comment: @robmayoff do you think you might give an example of doing such a thing?

Comment: @user309641 [IGFastImage](https://github.com/siuying/IGFastImage) - Obj-C tool used to find the size of an image given its URI, provides such a thing: please refer to IGFastImageHelper [parseSizeForPngWithData](https://github.com/siuying/IGFastImage/blob/1786d76e1718c247a002b4a3dd292a21a81ea70c/IGFastImage/FastImage/IGFastImageHelper.m#L109).

Comment: Just one thing, why do you cast to "unsigned int *) with the asterisk? I thought you could only do that with types that are objects, not primitives.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments! I also had to change width and height to this "            int32_t width = OSReadBigInt32(buffer, 16);
            int32_t height = OSReadBigInt32(buffer, 20);" otherwise the numbers I got were giant negative ones.

Comment: My bad, I somehow missed that from the specification, but integers in PNG are indeed in big-endian.