# I'd like to ask you how to deal with pictures under the forum, not to distort the picture

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Asked friends before, there are several views are as follows:

1. Let the server return the image size
2. Set imagview's `contentMode`

   - `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` This tile is not processed or will be deformed
   - `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` This proportionally displayed, too much blank, unsatisfactory
   - `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` This is proportionally filled, but this is just the middle part
3. Download the picture to get the picture size and then change the UI (user experience looks bad)

So would like to ask you how to deal with, there is no one in the case of the picture is not deformed to take the above part of the proportion of full, similar to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: you can resize the image as per your Imageview size

Comment: But my picture is obtained from the server, then how do I get the picture size is better?

Comment: check this post one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468747/get-image-width-and-height-before-loading-it-completely-in-iphone

Comment: ok,thank you,I have got that